# Websocket Secure error: Hostname not verified

Tags: android, websocket, server, ssl-certificate, okhttp

I am implementing a websocket server on esp32 and i am using okhttp lib on app running on android studio simulator.

I already tested with only ws/http and works ok.
I already tested with wss/https accessing site "wss://echo.websocket.org" and works ok.
I was told that the site "wss://echo.websocket.org" uses a certificate from letsencrypt.

When accessing my webserver on esp32 the android/okhttp error appear: "java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found".
So i searched in the web and "https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl#java", and i put the same certificate of the server inside the android app.
The error is gone, but new one appear: "Hostname not verified", see image in annex.

I want to use the https/wss protocol in a local area network for communication between esp32 websocket server and android / ios app.
Maybe in the future i will run a server in the cloud to communicate with the app and also communicate with the esp32 local websocket server(sporadic communication).
At first the esp32 local websocket server will not have a domain, only an ip ( doubt ).

I am using a self assigned certificate generated by openssl command:
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout prvtkey.pem -x509 -days 3650 -out cacert.pem -subj "/CN=ESP32 HTTPS server example"

I am not sure if the problem is in android/java or okhttp lib.

How can i solve this problem, already thinking about the production version ?

Notes:

I have control of both the esp32 local secure websocket server and the client application ( and cloud server ).
Esp32 local area network secure websocket server.
okhttp version: implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'.
I have very little knowledge about ssl/tls.

Thank's for the help.

```
// This solved temporarily the problem.
// I would like to generate the private key and certificate using openSsl in the right way.
// and using the hostnameVerifier correctly too.


HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier()
{
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session)
    {
        //return true;
        
        if( hostname.equals("192.168.0.8") )
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
};


private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                                                    .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                                  //.writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                                  //.readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                                    .pingInterval(25,TimeUnit.SECONDS)   
                                                    .pingInterval(25,TimeUnit.SECONDS) 
                                                    .hostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier)
                                                    .build();
```

[App Log Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChX7t.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are effectively disabling any security by returning true in the hostname verifier.  As such you may as well just use the addInsecureHost method to allow these requests.  Please don't use this in your production app obviously.

See https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/482f88300f78c3419b04379fc26c3683c10d6a9d/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/kt/DevServer.kt#L40

```
  val clientCertificates = HandshakeCertificates.Builder()
      .addPlatformTrustedCertificates()
      .addInsecureHost("192.168.0.8")
      .build()

  val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
      .sslSocketFactory(clientCertificates.sslSocketFactory(), clientCertificates.trustManager)
      .build()
```

Comment: I think that my problem now is how to generate the certificate and private key using OpenSsl command line tool to put the hostname correctly and after solve this, how to use this hostname inside "HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier()". I'm not sure if i'm completely disabling security, because i solved the first problem by placing the same server certificate inside the app (i don't know if it's in a safe place inside the app or if it should be inside a KeyStore for example, i don't understand this part yet).