# Possible to create Secure Websocket in Java for localhost only?

Tags: java, ssl, websocket, okhttp, java-websocket

Is it possible to create a Java SSL Websocket, so peers can connect using `wss://127.0.0.1`?

My current implementation is using `org.java_websocket.server.DefaultSSLWebSocketServerFactory`:

```
        WebSocketServerFactory socketFactory = new DefaultWebSocketServerFactory();
        // Make it secure
        char[] passphrase = tempPassword.toCharArray();
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(keystoreFile)) {
            keystore.load(fis, passphrase);
            KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            keyManagerFactory.init(keystore, passphrase);
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            trustManagerFactory.init(keystore);
            SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            ctx.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
            socketFactory = new DefaultSSLWebSocketServerFactory(ctx);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
```

But when I try to use this, I get the following error from OkHttp3:
`Transport exception caused by javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: connection closed`.
This is the full stack-trace: https://pastebin.com/raw/Y3RvqRrt

Comment: Usually exception stacktraces are much more extensive and contain more information. Please edit the question to include the entire stacktrace for the exception.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Added the stacktrace :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, insecurely you can use https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp-tls/okhttp3.tls/-handshake-certificates/-builder/add-insecure-host/

See the answer here [Websocket Secure error: Hostname not verified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64181090/websocket-secure-error-hostname-not-verified/64182186#64182186)

But assuming you want it securely, you will need to define the trusted certificates in the client.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/CustomTrust.java

```
    HandshakeCertificates certificates = new HandshakeCertificates.Builder()
        .addTrustedCertificate(letsEncryptCertificateAuthority)
        .addTrustedCertificate(entrustRootCertificateAuthority)
        .addTrustedCertificate(comodoRsaCertificationAuthority)
        // Uncomment if standard certificates are also required.
        //.addPlatformTrustedCertificates()
        .build();

    client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .sslSocketFactory(certificates.sslSocketFactory(), certificates.trustManager())
            .build();
```